# Excel 2010 Range.FormulaArray using Range.Replace

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to automate some daily work where i use an INDEX()+MATCH() array formula to grab some data from different workbooks into one 'master' workbook. Manually this works as intended, but now I want to automate this process.

I have struck the 255 character limit of the Range.FormulaArray property, and is trying to circumvent it by using the trick provided [here](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/01/10/entering-long-array-formulas-in-vba/), but no luck.

When running this code, the p1 part of the formula is inserted into the range, but the 2 .Replace's are not executed.

I have tried different variants of the "What" part of the .Replace function, both "X_X_X()" and the "{0}" and a lot of other with no luck.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Dim p1, p2, p3 As String
p1 = "=IF(G2<>"""",INDEX('C:\path\to\[document.xlsx]Sheet1'!$P:$P,MATCH(1,({0})*({1}),0)),"""")"
p2 = "B2='C:\path\to\[document.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$B"
p3 = "C2='C:\path\to\[document.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C:$C"

With ws.Range("R2")
    .FormulaArray = "=IF(G2<>"""",INDEX('C:\path\to\[document.xlsx]Sheet1'!$P:$P,MATCH(1,({0})*({1}),0)),"""")"
    .Replace "{0}", p2
    .Replace "{1}", p3
End With
```

The formula that i'm pasting manually is:

```
=IF(G2<>"";INDEX('C:\path\to\[document.xlsx]Sheet1'!$P:$P;MATCH(1;(B2='C:\path\to\[document.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$B)*(C2='C:\path\to\[document.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C:$C);0));"")
```

Comment: Could you place a shortcut with a truncated name to the files directly under `C:\ ` ? So `C:\path\to\[The_Document_Here.xls]` turns into `C:\thedoc.xls`

Comment: Do you need the formulas or just the results?

Comment: @Raystafarian i'm not sure what you mean, but I need to have the correct Formula in the range(the provided code is only a portion of the entire script). I'm using it to get the translation of certain texts combined in one document. All of this needs to be repeated for 100's of workbooks :D

Comment: I mean can you use the formula behind the scenes and just put the results in the cells?

Comment: What is exactly the issue?  Do you get any error message?

Comment: @MátéJuhász No, no error messages, just the initial formula left unchanged. I've read somewhere that it indicates an error in the formula, but if I do the replace manually there is no error.

Comment: @Raystafarian Thatcould be a solution, still the ideal solution would keep the formulas in the cells, to allow for updating of date without having to re-run the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did manage to solve it by first defining names for the ranges in the external workbooks in the 'master' workbook. By doing that I'm keeping the formula below the 255 character limit of .FormulaArray. 
A good nights sleep and fresh eyes on the problem was all it took :-)

Answer (score 1):

Consider first entering the formula normally and then converting it to an array formula just as you would in the worksheet:

```
Sub qwerty()
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=MAX(IF(A2>B1:B12,B1:B12))"
    With Application
        .SendKeys "{F2}" ' get into edit mode
        .SendKeys "^+~" '  use CNTRL + Shift = Enter
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

This macro should be run from the **Excel** window rather than the **VBE** window.

Comment: If I try that, i get a "Search string must be specified" error :(

Comment: @bwedel  **SORRY** ..............You must run this from the **Excel** window rather than the **VBE** window!

Comment: This was the only way I made it work with array formulas. I had to force a recalc of an array formula, and nothing else I tried worked: full book recalc, sheet recalc, range recalc, (these had no effect) setting range.FormulaArray (this produced "Unable to get the FormulaArray property of the Range class").